# A Function That is a Vertical and Horizontal Hyperbola at the Same Time

Tags: trigonometry

I'm trying to figure out how I could show that $r\sin(2\theta-\pi/2)=1$ never touches the lines $y=x$ and $y=-x$. Firstly, this trig equation simplifies down to $r\cos(2\theta)=1$, which goes to $r(\cos^2(θ)-\sin^2(θ))=1$ by using trig identities.
Here is a picture of the graph of this function:

[Graph of function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gQTNv.png)

Now, I understand that this graph looks like a horizontal and vertical hyperbola in one. I don't understand how I can prove that this graph never intersects the lines.
When I substitute the equations $\cos^2(θ)=x^2/r^2$ (because $x=r\cos(θ))$ and $\sin^2(θ)=y^2/r^2$ into the equation $r(\cos^2(θ)-\sin^2(θ))=1$, I get $x^2/r-y^2/r=1$, which I understand to be the equation for a horizontal hyperbola.
I'm not entirely sure how to go any further from this stage
Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Math SE!  Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your questions and make them easier to read.

Comment: as $\theta\rightarrow\pm\frac{\pi}{4}$, $r\rightarrow\infty$

Answer (score 1):

Your equation $\frac{x^2}r-\frac{y^2}r=1$ is correct, or put another way, $x^2-y^2=r$.
This is a horizontal/vertical hyperbola rotated by $45^\circ$.

If $(x,y)$ is on the line $y=x$ or on $y=-x$, then $y^2=x^2$, so $x^2-y^2=0\ne r$, so the point is not on the hyperbola.